# TSC TTP Pro Label Printing php error

Tags: php, apache, printing

I have this code from fpdf

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php

I did create the code to print 3 lines of text into the pdf that is coming out ok. When I give the print command the printer prints blank page.

Can you please lemme know what label code should I be using ? at the moment I am using

**L7163**

Or may be m using the wrong code.

```
$pdf = new PDF_Label('L7163');

$pdf->AddPage();

$query = "SELECT product, color FROM invoice_items WHERE tid = '$getID' ORDER BY id ASC";

$result = $conn->query($query);     


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $product = $row["product"];
        $color = $row["color"];
        $text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s", "$getID", "$product", "$color");
        $pdf->Add_Label($text);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Thanks.